# Building a C project on Ubuntu linux has error 'mysql/mysql.h no such file'

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, build

I know it's a stupid question but I'm new to Ubuntu. The C files in the project build ok but then I get the error 
mysql/mysql.h no such file or directory.
I've tried installing mysql server using apt-get but I still get the same error.
is there something else I should install to see the mysql files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `libmysqlclient-dev` package.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows eclipse mingw32, the  include path `mysql/mysql.h` is not working either. I have to use `mysql.h` without path but with Properties > C/C++ General > Path and Symbols > Includes adding the exact directory where `mysql.h` resides.

Its probably a problem of path delimiters on windows though I have tested both `\` and `/`.